# Evolution Mail Client: any support? Emails remain open after sending

Tags: email, evolution

Evolution 3.44.1-0ubuntu1 .
Ubuntu 22.04 .

Problem:
Compose mail. Send. Close Evolution.
Open Evolution, receive this message...

"Evolution quit unexpectedly while you were composing a new message. Recovering the message will allow you to continue where you left off."

When I choose no, the emails I sent earlier are opened for edits, as if none were ever sent and closed. All emails remain open after sending.

Would anybody know where and how to report bugs for Evolution?
The Evolution website has no page for bugs.

Thanks.

Comment: If you can reliably reproduce the behavior in a 22.04 LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment, then https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evolution . If you cannot reliably reproduce the behavior in a clean system, then do basic troubleshooting: Check your logs, check your /var/crash dir, reinstall the evolution package, etc.

Comment: I have the some problem. This is the bug report
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evolution/+bug/1978260

Comment: Please subscribe to Evolution mailing list: https://mail.gnome.org/mailman/listinfo/evolution-list and ask your question there. You can get help from Evolution developers there directly.

Comment: I have the same problem. It seems that it only happens to people using X11, not to those using Wayland, due to an issue with libcanberra-gtk3. https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evolution/-/issues/1972